# Avoiding OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument when read()ing large file

Tags: python, text, ram

I'm trying to read large .txt files in their entirety into memory (one at a time) to pick random lines until certain conditions are met. I can't use `readlines()` or `linecache.getline()` or similar because the file's lines are delimited by `\n\n` instead of `\n`. (Splitting on `\n` results in weird half-sentences, etc.) Ideally I don't want to split the data into chunks either, to avoid oversampling from a particular part of the file. Currently when I try to load the file into memory and separate along the file's delimiter using `read().split('\n\n')` the program crashes with

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Am I just out of luck here, or is there a workaround? RAM is not an issue.

EDIT: I just tried loading the file into memory using Python 2.7.10 and the same `read().split('\n\n')`, which works fine with no error. So I suppose my question should be more specific: is there a workaround for Python 3+?

EDIT2, per Ivan's insistence: You can replicate my issue using the following code

```
with open('file_larger_than_2gb.txt', 'r') as f:
    source = f.read().split('\n\n')
```

which works fine with Python 2 and triggers OSError with Python 3

Comment: Please upgrade your code to a [mcve] -- without one, it's impossible to say what causes the error.

Comment: The error is being triggered because the .txt files are several GB in size. This is a known issue (see: https://bugs.python.org/issue25626). I'm not asking what causes the error, I'm asking if there is a workaround.

Comment: I stay by my statement. Btw, there's no mention of `zlib` here (which is what that bug is specific to), so I highly doubt that it is the cause.

Comment: ok, updated my question again

Comment: WFM for a 2,5GB file on Python 3.6.5 win64 if I open it with `encoding='latin1'`. So this must be something with your file -- maybe an encoding issue, or something else is using the file or something.

Comment: Same for a 5G file. Size is definitely not an issue.

Comment: Tried your suggestion of specifying encoding by trying utf-8, latin1, and mac-roman. None of these fixed issue. I am using macOS so maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Also ensured nothing else is using file and the issue doesn't occur on any files in the dataset that are smaller than 2gb yet identical content-wise

Comment: Without the means to reproduce the problem, I can only make wild guesses. Separate `read` and `split` into different statements and show exception stacktrace to find out which of the three functions causes the error -- then its `man` page should say when its returns errno 22.

Comment: Finally, if your Python is from Homebrew or official site, you can get its source code and see what happens at C level -- what specific OS call fails and with what arguments.

Comment: To Apple, submit it surely. A Python bug is likely to be rejected because it's a _beta_ OS version, it's not officially supported.

Comment: Also, please write your finding as an answer and accept it. That'll help anyone else who hits the same problem as you did.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was caused by a bug in beta of macOS 10.13.6. Problem is fixed in the full release of 10.13.6, released on July 10, 2018.

Comment: But why is this an issue of macOS?

Comment: FYI, I am having this issue in ver `10.13.3`.

Comment: And in fact, after updating it to 10.13.6 still doesn't work.